# Android DateFormatter print Eastern Daylight Time instead of EDT

Tags: android, date, timezone, date-format, simpledateformat

So Im trying to print the string "Eastern Daylight Time" instead of EDT . This should be dynamic and not hardcoded. Looking into DateFormatter class did not lead me to an answer that worked.

[Here was an example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html) that allows me to format but  did not lead me to my specific answer.

I am getting the date back in the following format -

> 2013-06-08T00:00:00-04:00

Here are somethings that I have tried -

1)

```
 String dateString = changeFormatDateStringWithDefaultTimeZone(paymentConfirmation.getTransactionDate(),
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                "M/d/yyyy hh:mm a zz");



 public static String changeFormatDateStringWithDefaultTimeZone(String value, String ip_format, String op_format) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat opSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(op_format, Locale.US);
            opSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

            SimpleDateFormat inSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(ip_format, Locale.US);

            Date date = inSDF.parse(value);
            return(opSDF.format(date));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Err", "Failed to convert time "+value);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

2)

```
 Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 String todayString = DateUtils.convertDateToStringWithTimeZone(today);


 public static String convertDateToStringWithTimeZone(Date date){
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        String dateString = df.format(date);
        dateString += " " + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG);
        return dateString;
    }
```

These always print timezone as EDT and I want the string Eastern Daylight Time. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: It seems the Android resources of your device are different. Maybe you can try to update your Android OS.

Comment: running Android 6.0.1 and tested on two devices.

Comment: Well, the first example should use "zzzz", not "zz", but it would finally show, what the second way gives you. Have you also looked at the class `DateFormatSymbols` and its method [getZoneStrings()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getZoneStrings--)?

Comment: zzzz worked for me. Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Hm, while I expected zzzz to work, I still don't understand why `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.LONG)` does not work for you. By the way, I am also wondering why you get "Eastern Time" (or "ET") instead of "Eastern Standard Time" (EST). I still tend to suspect that there are device-dependent or Android-specific zone name resources. You should really print `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` and inspect `DateFormatSymbols`, too.

Comment: it was printing EDT and I wanted Eastern Daylight Time (not Eastern Time) . That was a mistake in my question. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your last edit of the question, the solution should be like this:

case 1)

The output pattern should be changed to "M/d/yyyy hh:mm a zzzz" (note the count of z-symbols to enforce the full zone name). Depending on the date and the underlying timezone, the formatter `SimpleDateFormat` will automatically determine if the daylight or the standard name is to be used.

case 2)

Use `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.LONG)` to enforce the long daylight name. If your default timezone is "America/New_York" then such an expression should print "Eastern Daylight Time". Note that the boolean parameter has been changed to `true`.